# Retrofit with multiple converters not working

Tags: android, retrofit2

Retrofit 2 can use multiple converters but bellow code is not working in my project........

```
adapterBuilder = new Retrofit
           .Builder()
           .baseUrl(baseUrl)
           .client(okClient)
           .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

Comment: please tell us more, what error are you getting ?

Comment: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path @MithunSarkerShuvro

Answer (score 2):

The order is important, and maybe it's somthing conflict in your converter.

It's hard to tell but infact you can indicate which api should use which converter by the annotation.
Than you'll more clear which step is incorrect.

See more from this post.

https://proandroiddev.com/retrofit-advance-multi-converter-c675e9483801

Answer (score 0):

So, as Jintin said, the problem is about what the converters return.
Inside Retrofit in the function in which it selects the converter for the request & response, respectively: nextRequestBodyConverter & nextResponseBodyConverter

You have (code from nextRequestBodyConverter which is same of nextResponseBodyConverter):

```
int start = converterFactories.indexOf(skipPast) + 1;
    for (int i = start, count = converterFactories.size(); i < count; i++) {
      Converter.Factory factory = converterFactories.get(i);
      Converter<?, RequestBody> converter =
          factory.requestBodyConverter(type, parameterAnnotations, methodAnnotations, this);
      if (converter != null) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (Converter<T, RequestBody>) converter;
      }
    }
```

As you can see if the returned converter is != null it will use it.
In your case you have that SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create() returns a valid converter for every Type I get inside "responseBodyConverter" & "requestBodyConverter".

To solve this I found 2 ways:

1] Edit "responseBodyConverter" and "requestBodyConverter" methods of your converter and return "null" when the "type" or an "annotation" doesn't match the required for your converter. Elsewhere you should return an instance of "ResponseBodyConverter" or "RequestBodyConverter" of your converter (if type or an annotation match one required by your converter)

For example, in the converter "SimpleXmlConverterFactory" if you have an annotation "@Xml" (or anything that is specific of this converter) you should return "null" if you don't have this annotation inside "annotations" arguments of those methods. If you have one return an instance of "ResponseBodyConverter", if you are inside "responseBodyConverter", or an instance of "RequestBodyConverter", if you are inside "requestBodyConverter".

If you can't edit or extends your conveters then you should:

2] Build a custom converter with 2 conveters as properties, in you case 1 "SimpleXmlConverterFactory" and "GsonConverterFactory". 
Init your converters inside the constructor.
As for point [1] you need a Type or an Annotation that is specific for the converter you need (for example if you have a json response you should use GsonConverter, if you have an xml response you should use XmlConverter).

Let's say you have defined those properties in your custom converter:

```
private GsonConverterFactory mGsonConverter;
private SimpleXmlConverterFactory mXmlConverter;
```

Then inside methods "responseBodyConverter" and "requestBodyConverter" you should do:

```
@Override   public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if(type or an annotation is specific of "GsonConverterFactory"){
       return mGsonConverter.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
    } else {
       return mXmlConverter.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
    }
}
```

Same for "requestBodyConverter" but in this case you will have:

```
if(type or an annotation is specific of "GsonConverterFactory"){
           return mGsonConverter.requestBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
        } else {
           return mXmlConverter.requestBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
        }
```

Remember that if you have more conveters you should return null if

```
type or any annotations doesn't match both "GsonConverterFactory" and "SimpleXmlConverterFactory"
```

Hope this is helpful :D

Have a nice coding and a nice day (: